# How to allow remote connections to my .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-server, firewall

I'm writing an application with both a desktop and a mobile app component. The desktop app is being written in c#, and I'd like to be able to open it up to act as a server for the mobile app (similar to what AirVideo does). How can I accomplish this without requiring the user to configure their firewall and/or router?

Ideally, I want to self host a restful wcf service in the desktop app. I've tried this already, but the automatic configuration of the firewall doesn't allow remote connections to the wcf service, since it appears to be hosted by the system process. Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Edit: I've solved the router problem as best I can through the use of the NATUPnP COM library (http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx). I still need to know how to allow remote connections through the firewall to a self-hosted WCF service without any manual configuration of the firewall (I'm okay with the user prompt to allow connections once the app is launched).

Comment: When using WCF, what type of endpoints are you configuring? Worst-case, you should be able to communicate via HTTP/HTTPS without any firewall changes. You could also look into Microsoft's UPnP framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382303(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Right now I'm using webHttpBindings since I want the service to be a REST service. I'm not married to configuration, so if there is another type of endpoint that doesn't end up being hosted by a daemon process, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2):

Set a specific port in your router that is designated to route to your server address,
So if your router real ip is a.b.c.d, you should set up that all communication to a.b.c.d:port# is being routed to your server local address. (a.b.c.d:port# --> serverIP)

The settings for this can be achieved from your router configuration.

In a situation where you cannot tinker with the router setting/firewall settings:
This means you cannot use ports to listen to incoming connections and can only use outgoing connections. to overcome that you will have to use a 3rd server with real IP-Address which will function as a listener for both sides. Typical scenario can be described as follows:
Client Side - A (Desktop)
Client Side - B (Smartphone)
Server Side - S (Communications Server)

1. S --> Open port for listening to incoming connections.
2. A --> Connect to S every x seconds to check if requests to do something are waiting.
3. B --> Connect to S. (issues a waiting request for A)

That way S is served as a proxy to glue both sides' communications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the router is not my problem at the moment. The issue I'm having is that the dialog that pops up the first time the application is launched to ask the user if they want to allow network connections results in a firewall rule being added that allows connections to my specific application (i.e. myapp.exe). Unfortunately, the system process actually ends up hosting the service, so the firewall rule is ineffective.

I can configure the firewall manually, but I don't want to have to ask users to manually configure their firewall.

Comment: Do you have both Firewalls enabled? (windows and router)

Comment: Yes, but this is a likely scenario for any user of my application. My users will be average computer users, so asking them to configure their firewall or router is out of the question.

Comment: In that case you cannot "listen" on incomming connections. You can only use outgoing connections which means you going to need a third computer to be used as a server with a real ip address.<br/>
I'll add that to my main answer.

Comment: Thanks GY for all your help, but this still isn't what I'm looking for. I have the app setup like what you describe right now, but I want to refactor to support a direct connection between the mobile app & the desktop app. I know it's possible, since another app I have does exactly what I'm trying to do (though I'm not streaming movies like theirs is). You can see what I'm talking about here: http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/remote-access.html.

I have confirmed, via netstat, that the desktop app is indeed listening for incoming connections.

Comment: Todd, I quoted this from the link you presented: 
"With Air Video you can access your videos anywhere on the internet. However in order to do that certain conditions must be met: 
•Your router must have a public IP address and must be accessible from internet. This is true for most of home internet connections.
•Your router must support UPnP or NAT-PMP protocols so that Air Video Server can setup the appropriate port forwarding. If your router supports none from these you will have to configure the port forwarding manually."
threfore - it cannot do it in the conditions you described.

Comment: The router is not my problem. I am able to programmatically setup port forwarding on the router to allow external connections. I accomplish this by using the NATUPnP COM library to communicate with the UPnP interface that is available on most routers. Examples here: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx.

I realize that not everyone will have this enabled, but this is as close as I can get.

The specific problem I'm having is that I can't connect to a self-hosted WCF service without some manual configuration to the host's firewall.

Comment: I'd like to try to help you solve that but I need to see a deeper description of the scenario, in which cases it works to be more specfic, ie: if you disable windows firewall - is it working?

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there GY. It does work if I disable windows firewall. It also works if I modify the incoming rule that get's created when the user selects yes on the "allow connections" dialog that is displayed when the application first runs. Specifically, I change the "Programs and Services" > "Programs" selection from "This program: <myApp.exe>" to "All programs that meet the specified conditions."